# How do I change the background color of an inherited style in Android layout styles?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

If I change the background of a child style, then it doesn't apply **any** other styles from the parent!

```
<style name="RemoteButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#556699</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ControlButton" parent="RemoteButton">

    <!-- THIS CAUSES IT TO IGNORE ALL THE PARENT STYLES SUCH AS MARGIN -->
    <item name="android:background">#E87E04</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

And this doesn't work (it's ignored):

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">#E87E04</item>
```

How do I give the child style a different background color?

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a custom style or theme, and you inherit from it, DO NOT use the `parent` attribute, instead of this

```
<style name="ControlButton" parent="RemoteButton">

    <!-- THIS CAUSES IT TO IGNORE ALL THE PARENT STYLES SUCH AS MARGIN -->
    <item name="android:background">#E87E04</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Do this, Notice the "." character.

```
<style name="RemoteButton.ControlButton">

    <!-- THIS CAUSES IT TO IGNORE ALL THE PARENT STYLES SUCH AS MARGIN -->
    <item name="android:background">#E87E04</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

You just keep using the "." character whenever you need to inherit your custom style.

Comment: I tried that and it still is not applying the proper margin!

Comment: Some Views do NOT support margin.

Comment: I know this does because it's applying the margin when I use the parent's style

Comment: Which View are you wanting to apply this custom style on?

Comment: I'm changing a `Button` view that's in a `TableRow` of a `TableLayout` of a fragment in the main activity of an app

Comment: I figured it out. setting `android:background` replaces the entire drawable on the button, thus remove all styles. I don't know why Android doesn't have a `backgroundColor` attribute that you can use in a style.